# -le, -il, -al, -el word endings

Tags: orthography

Is there a clear spelling rule about el, il, le and al word endings for the "uhl" sound? Please explain the etymological reason for these various endings.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The following question addresses one part of this: [How is the ending -le or -el determined?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11243)

Comment: There is no one clear rule, no. It depends on a combination of the etymology of each individual word, the vagaries of dictionary compilers throughout the centuries, and essentially random chance, meaning that a full explanation would be far too broad and long to fit into an answer here. The only reasonably clear rule about is for adjectives derived ultimately from Latin adjectives in _-ālis_ and usually corresponding to a base noun without the /əl/ ending: these invariably end in _-al_. (Well… I say ‘invariably’… I should probably say that I can’t think of any cases where that doesn’t hold.)

Comment: Thank you very much for answering my question.  It does make teaching spelling challenging but I'm glad to know I wasn't missing anything specific.

Comment: @Keats Be glad you didn't live before Webster published his dictionary. Or maybe happy, since there was no agreed spelling so you could teach whatever you liked.

Comment: But many people couldn't read or write in those days, so it didn't matter much.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no one clear rule, no. It depends on a combination of the etymology of each individual word, the vagaries of dictionary compilers throughout the centuries, and essentially random chance, meaning that a full explanation would be far too broad and long to fit into an answer here. The only reasonably clear rule about is for adjectives derived ultimately from Latin adjectives in -ālis and usually corresponding to a base noun without the /əl/ ending: these invariably end in -al. (Well… I say ‘invariably’… I should probably say that I can’t think of any cases where that doesn’t hold.) – Janus Bahs Jacquet