# Why is the English word "teasel" also spelled teasle/teazel/teazle?

Tags: vocabulary, contemporary-english

Why is the English word "teasel" also spelled teasle/teazel/teazle?

Reference:
https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/teasel

Comment: Related: [How is the ending -le or -el determined?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11243/how-is-the-ending-le-or-el-determined)

Comment: *Where* is it spelled in those ways, apart from in some dictionary? I have never seen those alternative spellings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How is the ending -le or -el determined?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11243/how-is-the-ending-le-or-el-determined)

Comment: Why can there be both *analyze* and *analyse*? (That is mostly a rhetorical question.) Several words have variant spellings.

Comment: It's done that way to tese you.

Answer (score 3):

Because the word is older than we’ve had strict laws for punishing people who don't spell words the very exact same way as other people spell them.

The OED gives these forms [behind its paywalled entry](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/198412) for the word:

> - α. OE tǽsl, tǽsel, ME tesel, ME tesell, tesyl(l, tesle, ME–16 tessel, 15
>     tesill, teasell, teassell, teysyll, 15–16 tessele, teazell, tezel, tezill,
>     16–17 teasil, **16– teasel, teasle, teazel, teazle,** 17 testle.
> - β. ME–15 tasel, ME–16 tasil, ME tasyl, tasylle, tasul, taselle, taysill,
>     ME–16 tazel, 15 tasill, tasyll, tassyll, 15–16 tasell, tasle, tazell,
>     tassill, 16 tassel, tazill, tazle, 17 tassell.

As you see from the part in bold, the Modern English forms persisting since the 1600s have been any of *teasel, teasle, teazel,* or *teazle*. Of those four, the two most commonly used spellings are *teasel* and *teazle*. It doesn’t matter though, since it’s still the same word no matter how you spell it.

In origin, the plant’s names in Old English had cognates in other Germanic tongues, and was related to the Old English verb *tǽsan* meaning to tease, with an additional instrumental suffix *‑lā* appended. This then gave rise to the Anglo-Norman word *teizel* after the French occupation in 1066.

And a thousand years ago, **everyone spelled *everything*** howsoever they pleased.

Comment: Can you add a bit of explanation of how this word differs from other words on which we've reached spelling consensus? (Probably just something like  *and it has never been in common enough use for a dominant spelling to emerge or be important* tacked on to the first sentence.)

Comment: Consider a word of about the same age - _deasil_. How would you pronounce it? It happens to rhyme with _teazle_. As @tchrist pointed out, strict spelling of every word is quite modern -- not more than 400 years old -- and before that peepul spelt thingz az they sed them. Spelling was individual, like pronunciation and handwriting, up until recently. Any words that have gone out of use are likely to come in several spellings; you can take your choice, but get rid of the idea that spelling has anything to do with English.